# Code folding in SQL Developer's SQL Worksheet

Tags: sqldeveloper, code-folding

Is there a way to enable code folding in Oracle SQL Developer's SQL Worksheet?  Using version  3.2.20.09.

Comment: Is there a reason this has been voted *off topic*?

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor: Display -> Show Code Folding Margin

Comment: Is there a way to add arbitrary, folding blocks?

Comment: @Craig: This has been asked on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467106/collapsible-region-for-pl-sql-developer) and unfortunately the answer is "no."